# Can angular have the same ng-if used several times on the page

Tags: angularjs

I cannot see the issue in my [html](/questions/tagged/html), but i can get the show/hide to work properly for a portion but not for another portion. It is the same `ng-model`. I am checking to see if feedback exists, if it does show one area, hide another. It is only working for the checklist. The checklist show and hides properly, but the message needs to display if the checklist is hidden. I know this is really simple, but no idea why it won't showing/hiding but i think it boils down to using `feedback.length` more then once. Can I do that? I have tried `ng-if="feedback.length>0"` and also `ng-show="feedback.length>0"` inside of the div for `myMessage`. The checklist is the only one that hides.

```html
<div class="col-md-3" id="myMessage" ng-if="feedback.length>0">
  <div class="alert alert-success">You have already submitted feedback for this user.</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3" id="checkList" ng-if="feedback.length==0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default questionHolder2">
      <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Thesis</strong></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        1. After reading, but looking back at the paper now, can you summarize or paraphrase the author's argument or main point that s/he is trying to convey to the reader?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `feedback.length` as many times as you want in your template. Maybe add a `<div>{{feedback.length}}</div>` outside of the ng-ifs and verify that it's set to what you are expecting it to be? It's possible that `feedback.length` is `undefined` or set to something other than a number, in which case your checklist might appear to work correctly but the message doesn't.

Comment: i tried that it returns nothing

Comment: then you need to figure out why `feedback.length` isn't defined. Is `feedback` defined to what you are expecting it to be? You will need to show your controller code and ideally a fiddle or plunker to get more specific help.

Comment: ok --ill keep looking into this